# PHP page wont load

Tags: php, html

File is empty on chrome inspect. All the other pages work fine and display a basic form. Never encountered an error like this. The form on its own works when put into html however i couldn't get that to communicate properly with the SQL DB. Any help that can be offered would be appreciated.

```
<?php 

//Connects to your Database 
$conect = mysqli_connect("db location","username","password", "forks") or die(mysql_error()); 

//Checks if there is a login cookie
if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_your_site'])){ //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page
    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_your_site']; 
    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_your_site'];
    $check = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());

    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $check )){
        if ($pass != $info['password']){}
        else{
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
    }
 }

 //if the login form is submitted 
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // makes sure they filled it in
    if(!$_POST['username']){
        die('You did not fill in a username.');
    }
    if(!$_POST['pass']){
        die('You did not fill in a password.');
    }

    // checks it against the database
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    }

    $check = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());

 //Gives error if user dosen't exist
 $check2 = mysqli_num_rows($check);
 if ($check2 == 0){
    die('That user does not exist in our database.<br /><br />If you think this is wrong <a href="login.php">try again</a>.');
}

while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $check )){
    $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
    $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
    $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);

    //gives error if the password is wrong
    if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']){
        die('Incorrect password, please <a href="login.php">try again</a>.');
    }

    else{ // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
        $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
        $hour = time() + 3600; 
        setcookie(ID_your_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
        setcookie(Key_your_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);     

        //then redirect them to the members area 
        header("Location: members.php"); 
    }
}
}
else{
// if they are not logged in 
?>

 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> 

 <table border="0"> 

 <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td></tr> 

 <tr><td>Username:</td><td> 

 <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40"> 

 </td></tr> 

 <tr><td>Password:</td><td> 

 <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="50"> 

 </td></tr> 

 <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> 

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> 

 </td></tr> 

 </table> 

 </form> 

 <?php 
 }
 ?>
```

As you can see the form is a generic html form with no formatting as it is my intention to leave that until everything is functional.

Comment: The code you've provided displays a form, not a blank page, therefore this is not enough information to reproduce the issue you're describing. Also don't use `mysql_error` with the `mysqli` functions, use `mysqli_error`

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/E0gp1 this is how it appears on the webserver

Comment: @matthew s Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem to close this thread. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$conect = mysqli_connect("db location","username","password", "forks") or die(mysql_error());
```

Try this:

```
$conect = new mysqli("db location","username","password", "forks");
if ($conect->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $conect->connect_errno . ') '
            . $conect->connect_error);
}
```

Let me know what error it throws if it doesn't work.

Comment: @matthew s Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem to close this thread. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$check = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'") or die(mysqli_error($conect));
```

Instead of this

```
$check = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
```